# mod_rewrite help

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to hide my directory structure and have all requests served out of a single directory where my files are located. The actual path where my files are stored is: `http://mydomain.com/dir1/dir2` but I'd like to be able to just point my links to just `http://mydomain.com/myscript.php`.

I have multiple script in this directory so I'm not sure how to go about this. Would I need a rule for each and every file I need access to or is there a wildcard that I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir1/dir2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule !^/dir1/dir2/ /dir1/dir2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will rewrite any request, that’s path does not begin with `/dir1/dir2/`, to the corresponding location with that prefix `/dir1/dir2/` but only if there is a file at that destination (see `RewriteCond` directive).